# Duplicate row for each item in column

Tags: powerquery

I can do things in PowerQuery but I can't find how to achieve the following result:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

The goal is to duplicate the last row (filtered with `Project Code=null`) for each item in `Project Code` column. I think duplicating the row as is is important to keep the `Metadata` Table and expand it later.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Grab all rows except null row

Get unique values of Project column in a list

Grab null row

Create row with the list and expand it

Put the two tables back together.

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
AllButNull=Table.SelectRows( Source, each ([Project Code] <> null)),
UniqueProjects=List.Distinct(AllButNull[Project Code]),
OnlyNull = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Project Code] = null)),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(OnlyNull,null,   UniqueProjects,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Project Code"}),
#"Expanded Project Code" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Replaced Value" , "Project Code"),
combined = AllButNull & #"Expanded Project Code" 
in  combined
```

Alternately, grab the last row instead of the null row:

Grab all rows except last

Get unique values of Project column in a list

Grab last row

Create row with the list and expand it

Put the two tables back together.

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
AllButLast=Table.RemoveLastN(Source ,1),
UniqueProjects=List.Distinct(AllButLast[Project Code]),
OnlyBottomRow = Table.LastN(#"Added Custom", 1),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(OnlyBottomRow,null,   UniqueProjects,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Project Code"}),
#"Expanded Project Code" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Project Code"),
combined = AllButLast & #"Expanded Project Code" 
in combined
```

[image]